# Convert decimal to currency and back

Tags: c#, math, currency

It's a little more complicated than that, but this is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Decimal num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
    Decimal num2 = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);

    Decimal total = num1 + num2;

    textBox3.Text = total.ToString("C");

    Decimal total2 = Convert.ToDecimal(total);

    total2 = total * 4.2;

    textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(total2);
```

Basically it's this: I have 4 text boxes, and I want to be able to put in a number in box1 and box2. Box three will multiply box 1 & 2 and convert it to currency. Box four will take Box 3s value and change it back to decimal and multiply a number. I can get it to work as long as total2 does not have a decimal. When it has one it will fail.

The program is basically a cash register program that you put in the following:

```
QTY (box 1)
Amonunt (box 2)
Subtotal (box 3)
Total (box 4)
```

Any ideas will be helpful.

Thanks,

Caleb

Comment: You really should give meaningful names to variables in the code.

Comment: This is not the "production" one.  This is one that I created just to post up.

Comment: I have one that is more labeled out, but this project is kinda basic, just cant figure it out for some reason

Comment: And yet its hard to see what is what, making people skip answering your question because it takes more time than usual. I'm just giving you a tip.

Comment: Ok, I will re post with the correct information

Comment: What is the failure? The code seems to be in working order.

Comment: You forgot to say how the current program fails, and what inputs you are using.

Comment: Error 1 Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'double'

Comment: If you had put that message in the original question, told us which line it occurred at, that would have helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that you are mixing decimal and double in this line:

```
total2 = total * 4.2;
```

`total` is decimal and 4.2 is a double literal. To write a decimal literal use the `m` suffix.

```
total2 = total * 4.2m;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly you perform operations on decimal variables holding currency values. Often it means maintaining a specific resolution (e.g 2 digits after decimal point for cents). Since *Decimal* is a general purpose type you need to maintain the required resolution programmatically.

example:

```
static Decimal  RoundToCents(Decimal value)
{
   return Math.Round(value, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}


Decimal num1 = RoundToCents(Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text)); 
Decimal num2 = RoundToCents(Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text)); 

Decimal total = num1 + num2; // no rounding is needed for additions and subtractions
Decimal total2 = RoundToCents(total * 4.2m);
```